# Why is my EntityManager not properly injected?

Tags: jpa, ejb, wildfly, entitymanager

I tried to build a project with manages Employees using JPA and Beans and JSF. I started trying to manipulated an existing user which I manually created in the database. (before I tried to read the data from the database, this worked well) I tried this in various ways, by getting different errors, so I assume that I do somethinbg completely wrong. My Server is Wildfly 8 and database is postgresql.

```
15:09:43,410 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-14) UT005023: Exception handling request to /time/modifyuser.jsf: javax.servlet.ServletException: Bei der Ressourcen-Einspeisung auf dem verwalteten Bean employeeManagerTool ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
  //...
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011878: Failed to lookup env/tbp.WAM.Tools.EmployeeManagerTool/entityManager [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]
    //...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.ExtendedPersistenceDeepInheritance.findExtendedPersistenceContext(ExtendedPersistenceDeepInheritance.java:49) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.injectors.PersistenceContextInjectionSource$PersistenceContextJndiInjectable.getReference(PersistenceContextInjectionSource.java:168) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:131)
    ... 93 more
```

So here is my Bean:

```
    @Stateless(name = "EmployeeManagerTool")
            public class EmployeeManagerTool implements EmployeeManagerToolLocal {

                @PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
                private EntityManager entityManager;

                public EmployeeManagerTool() {
                }

                public void modifyEmployee() {
                    Employee employee = entityManager.find(Employee.class, 1);
                    employee.setFirstName("NNF");
                    employee.setLastName("NNL");
                    entityManager.persist(employee);
                }
//just trying to alter the first entry, there is one with id=1
    // other CRUD methods
        }
```

My Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_Employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Version
    private int version;

    public Employee() {}
//some getter and setter...
}
```

My JSF file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>ejb-in-ear</title>
</head>

<body>

<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Save User" action="#{employeeManagerTool.modifyEmployee()}"/>
</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

My persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="timebudget" transaction-type="JTA">
        <!-- using hibernate as JPA provider -->
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <!-- Datenquelle ist PostGres -->
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/TBPDS</jta-data-source>

        <properties>
            <!-- Konfiguration für den PostGreSQL-Dialekt -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />

            <!-- hibernate Einstellungen -->
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />  
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />           
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Pleaaase, help me. I'm stuck at this for the whole weekend. I don't get what I'm doing wrong...

Standalone.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:2.2">

    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.batch"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.io"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"/>
    </extensions>


    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                    <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization>
                    <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <audit-log>
            <formatters>
                <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
            </formatters>
            <handlers>
                <file-handler name="file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </handlers>
            <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="file"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
        </audit-log>
        <management-interfaces>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true">
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
        <access-control provider="simple">
            <role-mapping>
                <role name="SuperUser">
                    <include>
                        <user name="$local"/>
                    </include>
                </role>
            </role-mapping>
        </access-control>
    </management>

    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:batch:1.0">
            <job-repository>
                <in-memory/>
            </job-repository>
            <thread-pool>
                <max-threads count="10"/>
                <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds"/>
            </thread-pool>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/TBPDS" pool-name="TBPDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bank</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>org.postgresql.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4.jar</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>bank</user-name>
                        <password>bank</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                    </validation>
                    <timeout>
                        <set-tx-query-timeout>false</set-tx-query-timeout>
                        <blocking-timeout-millis>0</blocking-timeout-millis>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
                        <query-timeout>0</query-timeout>
                        <use-try-lock>0</use-try-lock>
                        <allocation-retry>0</allocation-retry>
                        <allocation-retry-wait-millis>0</allocation-retry-wait-millis>
                    </timeout>
                    <statement>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:2.0">
            <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
            <concurrent>
                <context-services>
                    <context-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" use-transaction-setup-provider="true"/>
                </context-services>
                <managed-thread-factories>
                    <managed-thread-factory name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" context-service="default"/>
                </managed-thread-factories>
                <managed-executor-services>
                    <managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-threads="5" max-threads="25" keepalive-time="5000"/>
                </managed-executor-services>
                <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                    <managed-scheduled-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-threads="2" keepalive-time="3000"/>
                </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
            </concurrent>
            <default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" jms-connection-factory="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:2.0">
            <session-bean>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
            </session-bean>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
            <caches>
                <cache name="simple"/>
                <cache name="distributable" passivation-store-ref="infinispan" aliases="passivating clustered"/>
            </caches>
            <passivation-stores>
                <passivation-store name="infinispan" cache-container="ejb" max-size="10000"/>
            </passivation-stores>
            <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="default-file-store">
                <data-stores>
                    <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
                </data-stores>
            </timer-service>
            <remote connector-ref="http-remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="10"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
            <default-security-domain value="other"/>
            <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:1.1">
            <worker name="default"/>
            <buffer-pool name="default"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:2.0">
            <cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
                <local-cache name="passivation" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="persistent" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="ejb" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan" aliases="sfsb">
                <local-cache name="passivation" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="persistent" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:2.0">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
            <cached-connection-manager/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
            <expose-resolved-model/>
            <expose-expression-model/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
            <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:2.0">
            <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
            </mail-session>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
            <remote-naming/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:2.0">
            <endpoint worker="default"/>
            <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:2.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:2.0">
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid/>
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.2">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            </handlers>
            <filters>
                <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/8"/>
                <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
            </filters>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
            <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
            <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:2.0"/>
    </profile>

    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>

    <deployments>
        <deployment name="postgresql" runtime-name="postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc4.jar">
            <content sha1="b46544ef0eaf0405504089dcc71f36e3f190ef09"/>
        </deployment>
        <deployment name="wildfly-ejb-in-ear-ear.ear" runtime-name="wildfly-ejb-in-ear-ear.ear">
            <content sha1="eee0b026b1fac8c09a35bc0ef318a237d8d47c6e"/>
        </deployment>
    </deployments>
</server>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all for help;
If anyone getting the same error than me, maybe this helps:

I  used managed beans in JSF which are EJB, but I need to use CDI-Beans. As I deleted the Beans from the faces-config.xml everything works fine.

Sorry for asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are using Extended entity manager `(@PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)` with Stateless session bean `@Stateless`, but When you specify that an injected EntityManager is an extended persistence context, you should use `@Stateful` session bean, because extended EntityManagers still live beyond the scope of a JTA transaction, now you have 2 solutions:

1. change stateless to stateful session bean: in this case please note that extended entity managers create a persistence context when a stateful session bean instance is created that lasts until the bean is removed.
2. change extended entity manager to transaction-scoped entity manager by using `type=PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION`: The persistence context of a transaction-scoped entity manager begins when the transaction begins and lasts until the end of a transaction, but the persistence context of an extended entity manager will last for the entire length of the conversation.